# Is there a different way to float one item to the top of a sorted list of names?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

This is what I came up with to float 'default' to the top and sort the rest:

```
SELECT        'default' AS name, 'AAA' AS tag
UNION
SELECT        name, name AS tag
FROM            (SELECT DISTINCT TOP (100) PERCENT name
                          FROM            AccountManager
                          WHERE        (name <> 'default')
                          ORDER BY name) AS derivedtbl_1
ORDER BY tag
```

Is there a less complicated/better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT name 
FROM AccountManager
GROUP BY name /*To retain DISTINCT semantics from original query*/
ORDER BY CASE WHEN name = 'default' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, name
```

NB:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name 
FROM AccountManager
ORDER BY CASE WHEN name = 'default' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, name
```

would fail with `ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.` hence use of `GROUP BY`

Comment: thanks, that is just what I needed.  just curious, is the order by case technique something that's generally portable or is it a sql server thing?

Comment: @AaronAnodide - It is standard SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You can change how you sort them:

```
select name
from AccountManager
order by case name when 'default' then 0 else 1 end, name
```